# Reading PUT HTTP method from Page object

Tags: asp.net, http

I have a `System.Web.UI.Page` page which receive both `POST` and `PUT` HTTP requests.

Reading a `POST` data through the `Request.Form` field is fine.

But how can i get `PUT` data? `Request.Form` field is empty.

Is there a way to access the raw request? or better: The `PUT` data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution,
I was not using the good Field as Put data are contained in the body.

To access put data use:

```
Request.InputStream;
```